# variable "double" giving me error, and program is doing infinte loop?

Tags: java

I need to ask the user how many times he want to put his notes, then do a loop 
 how many times he need to put his note and finally calculate the moyenne, but im putting that double a = a+n; means that it calculate the notes number, and finally in s.o.p, im putting to divide the notes number on how much he asked first.
java is giving me error, any help?

Here is my code:

```
package minmax;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinMax {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x, y, z;
    System.out.println("Combien de notes vous avez? ");
    x = in .nextInt();

    for (y = 0; y < x; y++) {
      do {
        System.out.println("Mettez votre note :");
        z = in .nextInt();
      }
      while (z < 20 || z > 0); {
        double a = a + n;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Votre moyenne est : " + (a / x));
  }
}
```

Comment: double a = a + n;  Is this program compiling at all?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: `z<20 || z>0` can never be false.

Comment: @shmosel the dr told us that we should put in while the contradiction of the condition

Comment: And just for the record as newbies forget so often about that: please consider accepting helpful answers at some point.

Comment: @ghostcat yeah no problem man, i accept answers from everyone and thank you for you comment

Comment: @zx485 nop, I just didn't understand how to do it, my still a beginner

Comment: íSide note: you have a do-while loop, so that bracketed-indented line with the problematic double-attempt is extremely misleading, after fixing, it should be on the same level as the do and the while, without the curly braces.

Comment: By "accept" I mean that you actually **mark** an answer as accepted (here in the UI, the checkbox on the left hand side of the answer). And no, for the two questions you asked, you didn't *accept* an answer yet ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixes and suggestions:

1. Variables have to be initialized first (strictly without referring themselves), "updates" (referring themselves, the `a=a+something`, `a++`, `a+=something` kind of things) can happen only afterwards
2. In Java you usually bring variable declaration and usage close to each other, and remember that you can declare and initialize a variable in a single statement.
3. In the case of using a `do-while` loop, do not bracket+indent lines following the `while(...);`, such following lines are on the same level as the `do-while` loop itself
4. Whitespace preceding `.` looks strange, unless you break an expression into several lines

Put them together:

```
package minmax;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinMax {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Combien de notes vous avez? ");
    int x = in.nextInt();

    double a = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
      int z;
      do {
        System.out.println("Mettez votre note :");
        z = in.nextInt();
      }
      while (z < 0 || z > 20);
      a = a + z;
    }

    System.out.println("Votre moyenne est : " + (a / x));
  }
}
```

(Plus `a=a+n` became `a=a+z` for the obvious reason of `z` containing the number from the user, and the comparison directions had to be swapped - assuming that you want numbers between 0...20)

Comment: Especially `while(...); { }` is a tricky one, since an empty statement (`;`) is infinitely executed if the condition in the `while` statement is initially `true`.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes, first I was looking at that part as OP mentioned having an endless loop somewhere, then I saw it would not touch `z` even if it was a `while` loop without the semicolon, and only then I realized it was not a loop at all.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
double a = a + n;
```

You can't **define** a variable and initialize it with **itself**.

Meaning: it is not possible to declare `a`, but also assign a value to `a` that requires `a`.

In other words: the code you wrote really makes no sense. Maybe you should simply put: `double a = 0` somewhere above that statement, and then only do: `a = a + n` further down.

And of course: also use real names. `a`, `n`, those names mean nothing. Use something that tells the human reader about the intent of these variables.

Comment: I thought that was the problem what are you talking about, but the doctor told us that using this, we can calculate note we put in the output, but how to solve it?
How to calculate how much he put notes?

Comment: Can i use double a;
a += n ?

Comment: What prevents you from trying? Seriously: you don't learn programming from asking for explanations. You make experiments. And then you quickly find out: when you just write `double a`; then there will be a compiler error telling you about `a` not being initialized.